# How can I change text when ElevatedButton hover

Tags: flutter

How can I make the code below that works in onPressed state work in onHover state?

```html
class _MyState extends State<MyPage> {
  bool _flag = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => setState(() => _flag = !_flag), //
          child: Text(_flag ? 'Red' : 'Green'),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: _flag ? Colors.red : Colors.teal,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note : it didn't work  onHover: (isHovering) {setState(() { _flag = !_flag ;});},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onHover` is not a void function. It need to have a value. Try as follows:

```
Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: 5,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
              return ButtonItems();
            }));
```

And ButtonItems class

```
    class ButtonItems extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ButtonItems createState() => _ButtonItems();
}
    class _ButtonItems extends State<ButtonItems> {
      bool _flag = false;
  

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onHover: (value) {
              setState(() => _flag = !_flag);
            },
            onPressed: () => setState(() => _flag = !_flag), //
            child: Text(_flag ? 'Red' : 'Green'),
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: _flag ? Colors.red : Colors.teal,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: I have many buttons that I return from a list, how can I make this method work for them?

Comment: edited answer . have a look if it is what  you expected or not